# Can not install phpmyadmin Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm trying to install `phpmyadmin`.
However this is the error message I receive:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 - phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable 
Depends: php-cli but it is not installable 
Depends: php-mysql but it is not installable 
Depends: php-json but it is not installable 
Depends: php-mbstring but it is not installable 
Depends: php-xml but it is not installable 
Recommends: php-curl but it is not installable   
Recommends: php-gd but it is not installable 
Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
Recommends: php-zip but it is not installable
Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installable
```

Current installs...

- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- MYSQL 5.5.53
- PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25

Anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install php from ondrej repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Else use `aptitude` to install any missing dependence automatically

install it via `sudo apt-get install aptitude` then do `sudo aptitude phpmyadmin`,then it will show you any conflicts that are there and options to fix them